# Mathematical calculation in python abs function

Tags: python, math

I am trying to create the equation in python.
Sorry in advance if this has already been asked! If so, I couldn't find it, so please share the post!

I run into the problem that I don't know how to code the part in the red square (see equation [image: equation]).
As I understand it the "|u1|" stands for the absolute value of u1. However, if I code it like the equation is written i.e. abs(u1)abs(u2) I get a syntax error (which I kind of expected).

My problem is the line of code:

```
angle = np.arccos((Mu1*Mu2)/(abs(Mu1)abs(Mu2)))
```

My complete code is:

```
import numpy as np
from math import sqrt 

#first direction vector

#punt 1, PQ
#   [x,y]
P = (1,1)
Q = (5,3)

#punt 2, RS
R = (2,3)
S = (4,1)

#direction vector = arctan(yq-yp/xq-xp)

#create function to calc direction vector of line
def dirvec(coord1, coord2):
    #pull coordinates into x and y variables
    x1 , y1 = coord1[0], coord1[1]
    x2 , y2 = coord2[0], coord2[1]
    #calc vector see article
    v = np.arctan((y2-y1)/(x2-x1))
    #outputs in radians, not degrees
    v = np.degrees(v)
    return v

print(dirvec(P,Q))
print(dirvec(R,S))

Mu1 = dirvec(P,Q)
Mu2 = dirvec(R,S)

angle = np.arccos((Mu1*Mu2)/(abs(Mu1)abs(Mu2)))

print(angle)
```

Thins I tried:

- multiply the two abs, but then I'll get the same number (pi) every time:
  np.arccos((Mu1*Mu2)/(abs(Mu1)*abs(Mu2)))
- `+` and `-` but I cannot imagine these are correct:
  np.arccos((Mu1*Mu2)/(abs(Mu1)+abs(Mu2))) np.arccos((Mu1*Mu2)/(abs(Mu1)-abs(Mu2)))

Comment: Try `angle = np.arccos((Mu1*Mu2)/((abs(Mu1)*abs(Mu2))))`

Comment: Hi Anup, I see I haven't been clear, I tried that, but then I get 3,14 (pi) every time as an angle. I don't think that is correct.

Comment: Hi Florian, can you provide the expected output by using a calculator?

Comment: @SiHa indeed, however, I expected to get an angle between the two lines of the two points. This angle is in this case 3.14 (pi) every time. (as long as the line cross). which I don't think is correct. However, I might have misunderstood the equation

Comment: Don't use one-dimensional lines?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that the formula expects the two variables to be vectors, not angles.  (And I'm *absolutely* sure it doesn't expect angles in degrees!)  The numerator is the dot product of the two vectors, the denominator is the product of their magnitudes.

Comment: Just a thought  - are you getting confused with Radians & Degrees?
3.14 - pi. Pi Radians = 180°

Comment: @jasonharper Ah I see, I think that's where it went wrong! Will try this input to change my things!

Comment: @SiHa I don't think, I've #commented out the v = np.degrees(v) and I still get the same answer 3.14/pi every time. I think the problems lies with what jasonharper said. Thank to all for the feedback!!

Answer (score 3):

In the formula, the numerator is the **dot product** of two **vectors**, and the denominator is the product of the norms of the two vectors.

Here is a simple way to write your formula:

```py
import math

def dot_product(u, v):
  (x1, y1) = u
  (x2, y2) = v
  return x1 * x2 + y1 * y2

def norm(u):
  (x, y) = u
  return math.sqrt(x * x + y * y)

def get_angle(u, v):
  return math.acos( dot_product(u,v) / (norm(u) * norm(v)) )

def make_vector(p, q):
  (x1, y1) = p
  (x2, y2) = q
  return (x2 - x1, y2 - y1)

#first direction vector

#punt 1, PQ
#   [x,y]
P = (1,1)
Q = (5,3)

#punt 2, RS
R = (2,3)
S = (4,1)

angle = get_angle(make_vector(p,q), make_vector(r,s))

print(angle)
```

Comment: Hi @Stef, thanks for the code! I think you are correct. I just stumbled upon a webpage that does exactly what I need, so I am going to try to use that for my code, in combination with you code.

Answer (score 1):

From what I see, the result of your code would always be pi or 0. It will be pi if one of the mu1 or mu2 is negative and when both are negative or positive it will be zero.
If I remember vectors properly :
Given two vectors P and Q, with say P = (x, y) and Q = (a, b)
Then abs(P) = sqrt(x^2 + y^2) and P. Q = xa+yb. So that cos@ = P. Q/(abs(P) *abs(Q)). If am not clear you can give an example of what you intend to do

Answer (score 1):

Okay so apparently I made a mistake in my interpretation.

I want to thank everyone for your solutions!

After some puzzling it appears that:

```html
import math
import numpy as np

#punt 1, PQ
#   [x,y]
P = (1,1)
Q = (5,3)

x1 = P[0]
x2 = Q[0]
y1 = P[1]
y2 = Q[1]

#punt 2, RS
R = (0,2)
S = (4,1)

x3 = R[0]
x4 = S[0]
y3 = R[1]
y4 = S[1]


angle = np.arccos(((x2 - x1) * (x4 - x3) + (y2 - y1) * (y4 - y3)) / (math.sqrt((x2 - x1)**2 + (y2 - y1)**2) * math.sqrt((x4 - x3)**2 + (y4 - y3)**2)))

print(angle)
```

Is the correct way to calculate the angle between two vectors.
This is obviously not pretty code, but it is the essence of how it works!

Again I want to thank you all for you reaction and solutions!